# MarkLogic transform-to-json strips out link

Tags: marklogic

I can successfully retrieve the $name/text() value, but the a element gets stripped. What do I need to do to get it to include the link element and the text value?

```
<name type="string"><a href="http://localhost" target="_blank">{$name/text()}</a></name>
```

Comment: Please provide a snippet of code of how you invoke json:transform-to-json..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to make suggestions without seeing how you're invoking json:transform-to-json() and the output you're getting.

At a guess, you might need to specify the treatment of attributes for the full strategy in the configuration passed in to json:transform-to-json(). See

http://docs.marklogic.com/json:config